# How to share to git a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I make a new Dynamic Web Project, and then go team->share Project. Eclipse advises against using a repository in the same place so I do as I am told and create one somewhere else.
After doing this WEB-INF and WEB-INF/lib and also "Java Resources/src" end up with "?" decorators on them.
Is this bad ?, should I have done this differently ?.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use "egit". It is the git provider for eclipse

Comment: Once you have shared the project dont you then need to commit?

Comment: thy went away after i put stuff in. i am trying to make a clean version of my project. as pointed out below, rtfm, though i wouldnt have realised i have to go to all the different plugins to work out what the decorators mean. a separate question which i should try and find out the answer to is "is there a way for old people to have expanded decorator icons cos i cant see them half the time"

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [user manual for EGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations), the question mark next to a file denotes it is **untracked** by the GIT repository, and will not be version controlled until explicitly added.

Comment: which would be bad, wouldnt it. but they go away later when you add stuff, which isnt bad, is it.

Comment: @MarkLester 'Bad' is subjective; it wouldn't be bad if you don't want the items tracked.  It would be if you do.  So I can't say either way.